# How to get rid of stale Java icons from application switcher & dock?

Tags: macos, dock, java, application-switcher

I recently started seeing "java" processes with the default Java icon sometimes stay in the switcher/dock after Java Web Start applications are closed (OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks). This may have begun with JDK 1.7.0_76-b13. `pgrep java` shows there are no such processes. Force Quit does not work and they do not appear in the Activity Monitor.

I am behind corporate firewall/anti-virus and only use Java for local, proprietary applications. The disk has been verified by Disk Utility.

So far I have found that `killall -KILL Dock` will get rid of most of them but often leaves at least one called "java" with the command-line icon (black terminal window with green "exec" writing). Example from the Dock:

[image: Example of Java icons]

Does anyone else experience this or know - more generally - the cause and workaround?

Comment: Please add within your OQ if you ran `Disk Utility` on your Mac, and if you ran your anti-virus.

Comment: Does your problem looks like this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/17544259 ?

Comment: No: I expect icons to come up whilst the processes are running. The problem is that they (sometimes) do not go away when the processes end.

Comment: To help people try to help you in a known context, read and answer my 1st comment.

Comment: @danielAzuelos it's hard to interpret your comment - could you explain further why you think running Disk Utility causes Java icons to say in the dock? It's unclear whether you mean that these programs have ever run, or that something particular has been done with them (I have "run" Disk Utility and do not run a virus scanner locally - there are corporate ones on the network). These are real Java programs that I've run and have verified are no longer running. I'm not going around clicking on random adverts, and I only use Java for internal software.

Comment: If you ran `Disk Utility` and a local or corporate anti-virus, no one will make hypothesis about the bad state of your file system or your software environmnet. These 2 problems might be the cause of applications not terminating correctly. Hence this is important to put these 2 informations in your OQ and not just to reply to my comment. Note: I'll remove this comment within a few hours because it won't be usefull any more.

Comment: I'm seeing this same problem. The killall solution above had the same effect for me: it killed the "coffee cup" icon, but the exec icon is still in the dock and app switcher. I have not run Disk Utility nor do I have an anti-virus running during development. I'm getting this when working on an applet running under JRE 1.7.0_79 (I just upgraded though and was seeing it under the previous javac 1.7.0_75).

Comment: Did you see it on previous JDK versions, or did it start somewhere in the 70s?